# Scala Assertion unknown parameter on case class

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the below case class that translates directly a db table and where the id will be generated randomly on the creation of a new row.

```scala
case class Test(id: UUID, name: String)
```

Looking at the tests right now, I need to retrieve a row from Test and compare it with

```scala
val test1 = (...., "testName")
```

however I don't have the first parameter since it's created randomly and I would like to ignore it somehow...

I tried doing

```
test1 = (_, "testName")
```

but it's not valid.

Is there any way where I can ignore in Scala a case class parameter ?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to compare case class instances ignoring one parameter, is that it? A simple approach can be to copy a fixed value in the parameter to ignore.

Comment: In @GaëlJ's approach `equals` won't work anymore so you'll want to create a custom compare method that only compares on the second parameter.

Comment: @ComDubh what do you mean by `equals` won't work anymore? @Silvio's answer below is exactly what I suggested.

Comment: @Silvio defines a new method `myEquality` to test for equality based only on the `name` field., which is what I was referring to ("custom compare method"). @Gael, you didn't mention that, but perhaps assumed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we have

```
case class Test(id: UUID, name: String)
```

Here's a function that tests two instances of `Test` for equality, ignoring the `id` field.

```
def myEquality(a: Test, b: Test): Boolean =
  a == b.copy(id=a.id)
```

We can't explicitly tell Scala to ignore a field, but we can most certainly mock that field to be the correct value. And since these are case classes (i.e. immutable), we can't mess up any other unrelated data structures by doing this simple trick.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question posed, the answer is no. Case class instances are defined by the values of their fields. They do not have the property of identity like normal classes. So instantiating a case class with a missing parameter is not possible.